# Removing increment in outer loop doesn't change the output, however inner one changes

Tags: python, loops

My question is not around the output but more on how we are reaching at the output

Original -

```
n=5
i=0
j=1
line=''

for i in range(i,n+1):
    for j in range(j,i+1):
        line = line + str(j) + " "
        j += 1
    i +=1
    print( line)
```

I get my output as expected -

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Now if I remove the `i +=1`, I still get the same output. I'm not sure why?
To test it further, I tried removing the `j +=1`, to see whet

```
n=5
i=0
j=1
line=''

for i in range(i,n+1):
    for j in range(j,i+1):
        line = line + str(j) + " "
        #j += 1       ##Commenting the inner loop
    #i +=1            ##Commenting the outer loop
    print( line)
```

Output -

```
1 
1 1 2 
1 1 2 2 3 
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5
```

Now I'm confused why removing the outer loop does not change anything but inner loops changes the output? If I removed outer loop, how come it's incrementing?

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors that offset each other in your first version. Here's a correct version without manual incrementations:

```
n, i, j = 5, 0, 1

for i in range(1,n+1):
    line = ""
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        line = line + str(j) + " "
    print(line)
```

The real question is: why did the version with manual incrementation work? Let's try to follow the logic:

First, if you remove the `i += 1` line, the result remains the same, because the range `range(i,n+1)` is evaluated once to `range(0,n+1)`. Indeed, `i` has the value `0` when the range is evaluated. The code is equivalent to:

```
for i in range(0,n+1):
    for j in range(j,i+1):
        line = line + str(j) + " "
        j += 1
    print( line)
```

Let's look at `for j in range(j,i+1)`. Since `j` is incremented, it has always the same value as `i`, thus this range has only one element: `range(1,2)`, `range(2,3)`, ... The code is equivalent to:

```
for i in range(1,n+1): # j starts at 1
    for j in range(i,i+1):
        line = line + str(j) + " "
    print( line)
```

That is equivalent to:

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    j = i
    line = line + str(j) + " "
    print( line)
```

Or:

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    line = line + str(i) + " "
    print( line)
```

The thing to understand is that you don't build a line for each `i`, but you build a line `1 2 3 4 5` and you print intermediary results.

Bonus: the one-liner version:

```
print("\n".join(" ".join(str(j) for j in range(1, i+1)) for i in range(1, n+1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Manually increasing the counter i and j does not alter the state of the counter variable when the loop is iterated. Run this code to understand:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print(i)
    i +=2
    print(i)
    print('**')
```

Output:

```
1
3
**
2
4
**
3
5
**
4
6
**
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the inner loop to the outer loop is that in every iteration of the **outer** loop, created new inner loop, so the starting point of the inner loop ("j") depend on the variable "j" which defined out of the loops scoops, in difference to "i" which defined out of the loop but every iteration the "for loop" save metadata of the loop (i guess) and look on the last iteration.

and that the reason why in the outer loop the increment didn't effects - 
the for loop depend only the i that defined in the for loop and every loop he look on the last iteration value, when the inner loop every outer iteration creates new for loop and look on the value of j.

**In Addition**
if you using for loop on known DS (Array,Dict..) the pythonic way is to iterate on the elements and not using "C" styling of indexes :)